# Get NTHash property as string

Tags: powershell

I need to get a `NTHash` property. But when using `.NTHash` to get my property, I get an array of Byte.

When I use the command only, I have the property shown normally.

I tried to use `| Format-List -Property NTHash` & `| SELECT -Property NTHash` but both get array of byte.

I tried to convert the byte array using (I already tried enconding in utf8)

```
$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII
$enc.GetString($ADAccountInfo.NTHash)
```

And I get

```
�I�Ñ̊�
�>�zY
```

Here is my script with the [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sEaz.png):

```
$ADAccountInfo = (Get-ADReplAccount -SamAccountName Administrateur -Domain LOUTRECORP -Server WIN-LUS2BAD3LKC);

echo "the full result"
echo $ADAccountInfo

echo "The nthash given in array of Byte"
$ADAccountInfo.NTHash;

$enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
$enc.GetString($ADAccountInfo.NTHash)
```

Comment: Convert bytes to hex string

Comment: Thank that was what I needed c:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve my problem I needed to convert to hex string, thanks @gj13
Here is my script:

```
$NTHashBytes = (Get-ADReplAccount -SamAccountName Administrateur -Domain LOUTRECORP -Server WIN-LUS2BAD3LKC).NTHash;
$NTHash = ([System.BitConverter]::ToString($NTHashBytes) -replace '-','').ToLower();
```